# Refactoring a method and separating out logic that needs to be reused

Tags: c#

I'm tasked with refactoring an existing piece of code and separating it out into a separate class, so that the logic in separate class can be reused. I'm not clear on how to do it,

this is the method that needs to be broken down, I have simplified the code,

```
class TestClass
{
    private int maxRetryAttempts = 5;
    private int timetoLive = 30000;
    private void ProcessMessage(string label, IDictionary<string, object> headers)
    {
        var message = LoadMyConfiguration.Instance.Get(label);

        if (message != null)
        {
            maxRetryAttempts = message.RetryAttempts;
            timetoLive = message.TTL;
        }

        object retryAttempt = 0;
        object timestamp = null;


        if (headers != null)
        {
            if (!headers.TryGetValue("RetryAttempts", out retryAttempt))
            {
                retryAttempt = 0;
                headers.Add("RetryAttempts", retryAttempt);
            }
            if (!headers.TryGetValue("Timestamp", out timestamp))
            {
                timestamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
                headers.Add("Timestamp", timestamp);
            }
        }

        long currentTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

        try
        {
            if (((int)retryAttempt < maxRetryAttempts) &&
                (((int)retryAttempt > 0) ? (currentTime - (long)timestamp) < timetoLive : true))
            {
                //BUSINESS LOGIC 
                //INCREMENT RETRY ATTEMPT
            }
            else
            {
                //BUSINESS LOGIC
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

basically there is a retry logic that needs to reused in other projects as well. And the logic to retrieve certain fields from the dictionary also needs to be reusable. The `LoadMyConfiguration` instance is already a separate class. But the rest of the stuff needs to go into separate class with just the business logic in the `ProcessMessage` method which calls the new reusable class to check whether to retry or expire.

My OOPS knowledge is not that good and this is what I have so far,

```
public  class ReusableLogic
{
    
    public IDictionary<string, object> MessageHeaders { get; private set; }


    public bool IsExpired(long messageTimeStamp)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RetrieveHeaders(IDictionary<string, object> messageHeaders, out int retryAttempts, out long timeStamp)
    {
        object objRetryAttempts = 0;
        object objTimeStamp = null;
        object objDeliveryCount = 0;
        if (messageHeaders != null)
        {
            if (!messageHeaders.TryGetValue(RetryAttemptsHeader, out objRetryAttempts))
            {
                objRetryAttempts = 0;
                messageHeaders.Add(RetryAttemptsHeader, objRetryAttempts);
            }
            if (!messageHeaders.TryGetValue(TimestampHeader, out objTimeStamp))
            {
                objTimeStamp = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
                messageHeaders.Add(TimestampHeader, objTimeStamp);
            }
        }
        retryAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(objRetryAttempts);
        timeStamp = Convert.ToInt64(objTimeStamp);
    }

    public bool RetryAttemptsExceeded(int currentRetryAttempts, int maxRetryAttempts)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I know it's not much, but I'm not sure how to proceed further, I just need few ideas or tips on how to proceed.

Comment: My suggestion is 1. Complete the retry logic. 2. Find the similar part in the existing code. 3. Abstract them into a new method/class.

Comment: Can you show me a rough sample code?

Comment: I guess what they want is you to create a base class with the retry logic in it and only the business logic in your consuming class. Make an abstract base class with the retry logic in it and use 2 abstract methods (abstract methods need to be implemented by classes that consume the base class). Consume (inherit) the base class in your business logic class and implement (override) the abstract methods. In your base class at the location where it says //business logic call the 2 abstract methods.

Comment: do I need to make this reusable logic abstract? the consumer class is not going to add new logic to the retry logic. Is there a way I can create a reusable concrete class for this? The new class also needs to be testable.

Comment: What does `//BUSINESS LOGIC ` process? The headers dictionary? Some message not included in the example? Is the `headers` object used outside this class? A typical approach would be to create a class that takes a delegate, like a `Action<T>` or `Func<>`, for the business logic. But I would really prefer to keep the attempts & times as fields rather than some header dictionary containing objects.

Comment: the method gets the headers dictionary and a xml string. the business logic solely needs the xml. the attempts and times can only be sent as dictionary.

Comment: Take a look at Polly: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly